# Selecting last chronological record per customer where each customer has many records across many dates

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am trying to get the latest transaction for each member from a MySQL database where each member may have a different number of transaction records.  I also have to link the transaction table to the customers table to ensure I don't get any SPECIAL ORDER records.

Here's my SQL:

```
Select  membertransactions.maingym_id,
        membertransactions.member_id,
        membertransactions.action_id,
        Max(membertransactions.date_time) As 'Latest Transaction Date', 
        membertransactions.date_time

From    bd1.membertransactions
  Inner Join    db1.customers 
  On    membertransactions.member_id = customers.id
Where   customers.orderno <>'SPECIAL ORDER'

AND     membertransactions.main_id = 1

AND     Date_Format(membertransactions.date_time,'%Y%m%d') < '20121101'

Group By membertransactions.member_id, 'Latest Transaction Date'
```

I get a single row per customer, but it not always the chronologically latest row.  I'm really stuck here and would greatly appreciate any help offered.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using mysql, you can use a special feature of mysql to get this done simply. Here's how:

```
select * from (
    Select
        membertransactions.maingym_id,
        membertransactions.member_id,
        membertransactions.action_id,
        membertransactions.date_time
    From bd1.membertransactions
    Join db1.customers On membertransactions.member_id = customers.id
    Where customers.orderno <> 'SPECIAL ORDER'
    AND membertransactions.main_id = 1
    AND Date_Format(membertransactions.date_time,'%Y%m%d') < '20121101'
    order by membertransactions.date_time desc) x
Group By member_id
```

I have removed the `max(date)` stuff altogether and the inner select gets all the records in latest-first date order, then the outer select groups by member_id. Here's the key: in mysql if you have a group by *without* aggregating the remaining columns you get the *first* row for the group.

Other databases will give a syntax error on this SQL, but in mysql it works like a charm

Also note the more readable formatting. I have never understood why people use "left align second word of each line" formatting. I wish I could find the person that first did that and have him flogged.

Comment: Thanks for this Bohemian, unfortunately I get an error:  **Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'membertransactions.member_id' in 'group statement'** when trying to run this code.  Any further ideas?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @enCue I just quickly typed it in. Fixed now - it should be just `Group By member_id`. See edited answer